# What block hash function and transaction signature method does EOS use?

Tags: transactions, blocks, cryptography, hash

What hash function does EOS use for creating a block. Is it SHA-256?

In addition, what procedure for signing a transaction is used? RSA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Block producers use SHA-256 to generate the digest and ECDSA to sign the block. Producers may sign using a K1 key (secp256k1 curve, used by Bitcoin) or an R1 key (P-256 curve, a NIST standard). Likewise, users may use K1 or R1 keys to sign transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Signatures are produced using EC-DSA.

Comment: Can you offer any references to your answer?